# Error out shell script if PL/SQL program fails

Tags: shell-script, ksh, sql

In the shell script, I am calling a PL/SQL stored procedure.

```
sqlplus -s <<EOF
$v_fcp_login
set head off feed off serverout on size 1000000
exec XXIRIS_TEST_K.XXIRIS_TEST('$v_1',$v_2,$v_3,'$v_4',$v_5);
exit
EOF
```

But when there is an error in the PL/SQL block, I need to error out shell script, which is running as a host concurrent program in Oracle, but it is not doing so.

Comment: if that block is normal shell code, then you need to use `eval` or run the script in a different manner — `exec` will substitute that shell with the call, so exit can never be reached. And to only exit on error, assuming plsql has sane exit codes, use `|| exit` at the end of the call. It will still probably be moot, since it will only exit the current shell and you seem to want one more.

Comment: Just an FYI, when dealing with usernames/passwords with sqlplus you should be using Oracle Wallets: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#CHDCJDHA

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get SQL*Plus to error out if a SQL error occurs. You can do this by adding:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
```

to your SQL script (probably up top). You can also give different codes (small non-negative integers; non-zero = failure) in place of the word `FAILURE`.

These will come back to your shell script in `$?`. So you can then have your shell script react to it. Altogether, it'd look something like this:

```shell
sqlplus -s <<EOF
$v_fcp_login
set head off feed off serverout on size 1000000
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
exec XXIRIS_TEST_K.XXIRIS_TEST('$v_1',$v_2,$v_3,'$v_4',$v_5);
exit
EOF
if [ 0 -ne "$?" ]; then
    echo "Stored proc blew up." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Of course, you can use different exit codes to indicate different things (e.g., if you were calling multiple stored procedures, you could exit 1 for the first one blowing up, exit 2 for the second, etc.)